# Examples of ArcGIS Server 10.x REST map service layers with OpenLayers 3?

Tags: arcgis-server, openlayers, arcgis-rest-api

I am looking around, but so far I have only seen examples for OpenLayers 2 that use ArcGIS REST map services (dynamic, not cached). Is there a way I can add an ArcGIS 10.x REST map service to OpenLayers 3?

Comment: Have you looked at ol.source.TileArcGISRest?  It dynamically gets a "tile". 

"Layer source for tile data from ArcGIS Rest services. Map and Image Services are supported."

Comment: Here is an example:
http://openlayers.org/en/v3.7.0/examples/arcgis-tiled.html

Comment: @PolyGeo I say in my question that 'I have only seen examples for OpenLayers 2'...but I am trying to use OpenLayers 3...sorry if that wasn't clear

Comment: Thanks I will try that..I didn't understand that 'TileArcGISRest' can be used for an ArcGIS dynamic map service....

Comment: are there any examples out there to select a feature from an ArcGIS map service? I see there is no 'getSource' method for TileArcGISRest layers.